# Rotating Display Images & Changing color of their parts

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to display an object in webpage that can be rotated (360 degree). Also as per the selection we need to change the color of certain parts. For example please take a look at the below link.

http://www.adidas.com/us/mi-gazelle-shoes/4001877_M.html?pr=CUSTOMIZE_IMG_mi%2520Gazelle%2520Shoes&cm_sp=MIADIDAS_HOME-_-CUSTOMIZE_GAZELLE

or

```
go to adidas.com/us and select customize any shoes
```

or see screenshot

[image]

As per my idea, we can split the object shapes to tiny pieces and put it together in css for each side and Approx 8 images to show the 360 degree view of image for each side. Also on clicking on each piece we can programatically change the color of that piece using javascript.

Have you guys ever used anything like this in your page or if you know any plugins to achieve this. Any suggestions for this will be greatly appreciated.

I dont want any code snippets, i just want a general idea how to achieve this easily (like that in adidas website).

**Some Thoughts.**

1. I dont have much knowledge about svg, does the svg come in anyway handy for this?
2. Any third party plugin for 360 degree display image by providing a set of images.
3. Draw map in an image using dreamweaver or some tools and programatically change the color of that section, is that possible?

Comment: the website from the linke does not work for me. The main banner shows nothing. So don't understand what you mean. I'm using Google Chrome, latest version. Looks like there is something wrong with the website of a fairly famous sport-fashion brand.

Comment: Please go to http://www.adidas.com/us/ and select customize any shoes.

Comment: still not working, the loading indicator runs for a while before disappearing and nothing is shown or happens then.

Comment: I think its something with your browser coz the page is working fine with me.